# what's a way to create an array out of a string of digits INCLUDING spaces?

Tags: javascript

I am needing to maintain spaces in a string of numbers while turning it into an array:

```
const input = "414234513322112251 22113322"
```

I need to split this string into an array where each index is two digits:

```
const arr = [
  '41', '42', '34',
  '51', '33', '22',
  '11', '22', '51',
  '22', '11', '33',
  '22'
]
```

I simply need to maintain the space in that array. I have tinkered around with regex but have hit a wall. Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: what do you mean with maintaining? where should the space go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the space in the array

```js
const str = "414234513322112251 22113322"
const arr = str.match(/(\d{2}| )/g)
    console.log(arr)
```

Here you know where the space is, you can splice it in where you want

```js
const str = "414234513322112251 22113322"
const spacePos = str.indexOf(" ")
const arr = str.match(/\d{2}/g)
console.log(spacePos,arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you want to do with the space? "Maintaining" it doesn't tell me a lot. Also, will the string always have a length that is a multiple of 2?

I'll do my best to answer the question with what I have, I hope this helps you:

```js
let str = "549273776394728601 87270515"
let result = [];

let i = 0;
while(i < str.length){
    let toAdd = "";
    toAdd += str.charAt(i);
    if(str.charAt(i) !== " "){
       toAdd += str.charAt(i + 1);
       i++;
    }
    i++;
    result.push(toAdd);
}
        
console.log(result);
```

This solution will only work for inputs with even-amounts of numbers, and it will treat a space as a "skip". So this string: `"1122334455 667788"` will come out as `["11","22","33","44","55"," ","66","77","88"]`, but this string: `"11223344 556677889"` will break it. (Unless you add a simple check in my code to make sure it doesn't execute the second push unless `i + 1 < str.length - 1`)

Hope this helps and that this is the answer you were looking for...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split ever two characters, you can use the following regular expression

```
const arr = input.match(/.{1,2}/g);
```

Comment: That does not really look like OP's expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet.

```
const input = "4414234513322112251 22113322";
let regex = /\d{2}/g;

console.log(input.match(regex))
```

This code snippet groups around two consecutive digits and ignores the group "1 " as shown in your example.

I hope this helps. :D

Comment: @mplungjan , I am sorry I did not see your answer. It wasn't there while I was writing mine and it appeared after I submitted my solution.